# python postgresql TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for loop

Tags: python, postgresql

i have an postgresql database

#p1 = {613309872640, 135117629824, 880993344004, 158175822853, 1073752495240, 216760058760, 447123298313, 912909533578, 762965475336, 306930570381, 972176171275, 6619746319, 343850096144, 764400555409, 546205930000, 528687305491, 404493333779, 77590592280, 855904184346, 936056534938, 661500784670, 141923831071, 562200894625, 567019890466, 832033035811, 72309584292, 364867195430, 190122917676, 144896917811, 580869171253, 1627505081, 627702833596, 644839868222, 172977438016, 1031295913668, 463277927492, 238807296070, 500185745223, 780490132936, 947594928202, 888064501323, 992713674444, 453125481684, 502841610453, 81933315933, 94767975264, 103246266465, 275027812832, 276760003301, 420374924396, 263072530544, 203425700337, 334072272115, 917262638965, 989106489206, 598614815351, 328241935477, 554909676025}

i use this code

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "...",
                                  password = "...",
                                  host = "...",
                                  port = "...",
                                  database = "...")

c = connection.cursor()


.......

match_ids = set()
        for chunk in p[1]:          
            for id in c.execute("SELECT S.val1 FROM table1 as F JOIN table2 AS S ON F.val2_id=S.val2_id WHERE F.val3=%s and F.val4=%s", (p[0], chunk)):
                match_ids.add(id[0])
                print(match_ids)
```

i can use this code on sqlite
but, I get an error when using postgresql

Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
runcell(0, 'C:/Users/....../test1.py')
{613309872640, 135117629824, 880993344004, 158175822853, 1073752495240, 216760058760, 447123298313, 912909533578, 762965475336, 306930570381, 972176171275, 6619746319, 343850096144, 764400555409, 546205930000, 528687305491, 404493333779, 77590592280, 855904184346, 936056534938, 661500784670, 141923831071, 562200894625, 567019890466, 832033035811, 72309584292, 364867195430, 190122917676, 144896917811, 580869171253, 1627505081, 627702833596, 644839868222, 172977438016, 1031295913668, 463277927492, 238807296070, 500185745223, 780490132936, 947594928202, 888064501323, 992713674444, 453125481684, 502841610453, 81933315933, 94767975264, 103246266465, 275027812832, 276760003301, 420374924396, 263072530544, 203425700337, 334072272115, 917262638965, 989106489206, 598614815351, 328241935477, 554909676025}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\.....\test1.py", line 208, in <module>
    for id in c.execute("SELECT S.val1 FROM table1 as F JOIN table2 AS S ON F.val2_id=S.val2_id WHERE F.val3=%s and F.val4=%s", (p[0], chunk)):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: can you check with the executing below line?
c.execute("SELECT S.val1 FROM table1 as F JOIN table2 AS S ON F.val2_id=S.val2_id WHERE F.val3=%s and F.val4=%s", (p[0], chunk))

might get some info

Comment: I don't get an error when I run that code, I think there is a problem with the for id loop,

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback here?

Comment: What was the output of the individual execution of that query? Bcz problem seem to be from that query. The output seems to be None.

Comment: i can get this result for sqlite,  {'12288:rxlCaqt6z7RgnhVzQnaNoroE+KktJImrR1YNt35L+s5ENOeQiV1Li/kWpbN:r6klghyaNvXjYNPLeYeXV1i/kW', '12288:3nTGJQbCfvseE2rB+NR3mPOENHaXtbPteWR5L+s5ENOeQiV1Li/km:3nWRNrsR3lFPte6LeYeXV1i/km', '12288:VxlCa9t6z7RgnhVzQnaNoroE+KktJImrR1YNtG5L+s5ENOeQiV1Li/kUx:V6vlghyaNvXjYNkLeYeXV1i/k', '12288:tnPGJQbCfvseE2rB+NR3mPOENHaXtbPteWR5L+s5ENOeQiV1Li/km:tnqRNrsR3lFPte6LeYeXV1i/km'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using replacing below snippet with your snippet.

```
for chunk in p[1]:
    for id in c.execute("SELECT S.val1 FROM table1 as F JOIN table2 AS S ON F.val2_id=S.val2_id WHERE F.val3=%s and F.val4=%s", (p[0], chunk)) or []:
        match_ids.add(id[0])
        print(match_ids)
```

Actual issue seems that, query can't fetch the result.